# k-th largest of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability

I have a sequence of i.i.d continuous random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$. I want to find the probability that $X_n$ is the $k$-th largest of $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$. I want some hint.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a rank to each $X_i$, $1$ for the tallest, $2$ for the next tallest, and so on. All permutations of ranks are equally likely. (The probability of a tie anywhere is $0$, since the distribution is continuous. With discrete distributions the problem becomes far more complicated.)